# Can you get to the DbMigration T4 template?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have created a class which allows you to control the migration between versions of my database but I want to customise the automatically generated migration code file. As default when 'migration-add' is called it defines a migration class which has an abstract class called 'DbMigration'. I have created a class which has this as its base class and it works great but I wanted to modify a T4 template (if possible??) that gets used when migration-add is called so that the newly created migration module uses my base class and not the DbMigration. Also I need to add a constructor.

I have been looking for ages and I can find how to get T4 templates for most of EF but nothing is mentioned for the migration scaffolding which I guess is because its created via the Package Manager Console with the Add-migration command???? So I dont know its this is even possible??????

Thanks in advance!!!

PS Forgot to mention I am using code first.